# Writing Bytes To Device every Second in C

Tags: c, linux

I am just having troubles with a function which attempts to constantly write every second to a terminal in order to continuously receive data:

```
int plash(int filedes) {
    static struct p_1 = {
        .X = 1,
        .Y = 10,
        .Z = 13
    };
    return write(fd, &p_1, sizeof(p_1));
}

int elli() {
    while (1) {
        int g = plash(fd);
        printf("Writing to port:%d\n", g);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint8_t buffer[128];
    int bRead;
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    while (fd > 0) {
        elli();
        bRead = read(fd, buffer, 128);
        printf("Got %i Bytes\n", bRead);
    }
}
```

I think the program writes to the port but it is not performing the read function called afterwards. Can you guys give me a hand on that?

Comment: Can you please try to more clearly explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @UpAndAdam.. What I am trying to do is to send every second the struct present in plash() in order to get constantly data from a terminal device; After sending every second this struct I am able to continuously reading from that port... The problem is that I do not really know how to do it. By the way, fd is an integer int fd;...Thanks!

Comment: you just rewrote exactly what you said above, if it was clear the first time I wouldn't have asked.  Give us a higher level explanation, I don't mean to be rude but I really care what the hell you call your horribly named functions, they aren't really the problem or the solution.. 

What are you actually trying to accomplish and learn here... example: I'm trying to simulate some activity from a terminal and want my process to able to read it.  or I'm trying to commnunicate in a really obtuse manner by reading writing through a DEVICE as though it were shared memory or a file.

Answer (score 4):

In your `elli` function you have an infinite loop, that's way you're not able to read. You should change your `while` loop condition or maybe try to create a program using concurrent computing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Qiu.. Yeah but what would you suggest in that sense? I do not really know how to make that function loop without this infinite variant..

Comment: You haven't expressed clearly what you are trying to do.  You don't know how to make it worth WITH an infinite loop either, so that statement is rather useless.

Comment: Does the program even compile? plash() takes filedes and write() uses fd. That said, sleep(1) puts the entire process to sleep and when the process wakes up, you will enter the infinite loop again.  This is what Qiu is indicating. The suggestion is to use threads if possible for diferent tasks OR use s sync mechanism for elli to give up the cpu for some time.

Comment: Thanks @lsk but how can I use a thread in this way? What is this sync mechanism?? Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you've described so far you have multiple choices all of them are advanced and require `parallel processing` you can do this through `IPC`, `multiple processes`, or `multiple threads`.

In a nutshell you'll want one of these pseudo-processes to be a producer, who writes data, and the other to be a reader, who consumes said data.   This is a classic parallel computing problem; the reader-writer scenario.

A quick gander through basics of forking or spawning threads or reader-writer should provide a multitude of examples.

Comment: Thank you very much @UpAndAdam... I am going to read a little bit about what you have described.. Thanks for your recommendation!